# Opening a newly created man file in a text editor BASH

Tags: bash, manpage, groff

I've created a new groff file, now named junk-man.1.gz (as I've been asked to gzip file).

How do I view the man file in gedit? I want to be able to view the man file as in all its presented glory, not the original groff code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to display a groff file as a manpage you have to render it.

Try:

```
zcat junk-man.1.gz | groff -man -Tascii
```

This should work.